# Webview - onPageFinished is not called

Tags: android, caching, webview

In my App i want to cache a webapage in the background with a hidden webview (at the same time another webview is visible to the user and loads another url).
I start the caching in onResume. Here are the code snippets:

1.) onResume:

```
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
      new LibraryCacher().startCaching(this);
      //some more code...
   }
```

2.) LibraryCacher:

```
   public class LibraryCacher extends BasicClass {

      public LibraryCacher () {}

      public void startCaching(Context context) {
         getLogger().debug("startCaching()");

         if (NetworkHandler.isOnline(context) == false) {
            getLogger().info("We are offline, no caching");
            return;
         }
         final String URL_TO_CACHE = "http://myUrl.com";
         WebView w = new WebView(context);
         w.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         WebSettings webset = w.getSettings();
         webset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webset.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
         webset.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
         webset.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
         webset.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
         webset.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
         webset.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
         webset.setAppCachePath(w.getContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
         webset.setAllowFileAccess(true);
         webset.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

         w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                getLogger().debug(url + " caching...");

            }
           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                 getLogger().debug(url + "cached");
           }
        });
        w.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        getLogger().debug("load Url");
        w.loadUrl(URL_TO_CACHE);
      }
   }
```

At the FIRST-CACHE-TRY (app starts the first time) logcat looks like this:

1. startCaching()
2. load Url
3. http://myUrl.com caching...

After that i put the app in the background and resume it. So, at the SECOND-CACHE-TRY logcat looks like this:

1. startCaching()
2. loadUrl
3. http://myUrl.com caching...
4. http://myUrl.com cached

My question:

Why doesn't the webview invoke its method onPageFinished at the first try?

**EDIT :**

It works, if i invoke

```
new LibraryCacher().startCaching(this);
```

in onPageFinished of the other webview, which is visible to the user and loads simultaneously another url. 
Does anyone know why?

Comment: You have `onResume` executing the function which happens as you have specified.  Try doing this for `onCreate` or `onStart`

Comment: Now, onpageStarted-method is called, but not onPageFinished. I edited my post.

Comment: @JeremyMiller: onCreate is no alternative for me, because i want to refresh the cache after a specific period of time the app was in the background

Answer (score 1):

Webviews in android seem to have some shared state. In my case, `onPageFinished` was never called, because i used:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    webView.pauseTimers();
}
```

On a **completely different** webview, in a different activity.